# Select 50 to 100 rows from datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I need to select rows 50 to 100 from a datatable. I have tried for the first 50 rows using this code:

```
dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(50)
```

Now I need rows 50 to 100 from the datatable. How do I do this?

Comment: There are probably better duplicates as well, take a look through [a simple google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=linq+paging+results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Skip` method

```
dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Skip(50).Take(50)
```